# AWS S3 presigned URL contains X-Amz-Security-Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a presigned URL for a file in my S3 bucket using go sdk.

When I run the program from command line, I get the presigned URL which doesn't contain the X-Amz-Security-Token.

But if I use the same code from a lambda function, I always get the X-Amz-Security-Token in the URL.

I am not sure why this behaviour is different.

Here is the code -

```
func CreatePreSignedURL(bucketName string, path string) (string, error) {

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(path),
    })

    urlStr, err := req.Presign(60 * time.Minute)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error in generarting presigned URL is ", err)
        return urlStr, err
    }

    return urlStr, nil
}
```

The URL generated by lambda is quite long, for my application I am expecting a shorter URL without X-Amz-Security-Token

Comment: Have you got the same [env vars](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/#hdr-Environment_Variables) and [config files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/#hdr-Shared_Config_Fields) on both hosts?

Comment: If `x-amz-security-token` is not present it also means that is not required in the current environment where is generated. I solved adding and if statement to check and process the `x-amz-security-token` only if present and my frontend works both locally and deployed in a lambda.

Answer (score 11):

When the function is run in your command line, it generates pre-signed URLS with IAM credentials possibly stored in environment variables or in `~/.aws/config`.

Temporary credentials are assigned for the IAM role associated <sup>[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/accessing-resources.html)</sup> with the function when invoked in AWS Lambda environment.

AWS necessitates that requests made with temporary credentials include `x-amz-security-token` header. <sup>[2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#UsingTemporarySecurityCredentials)</sup>

I don't find the length of the URL to be an issue here.

If you like to keep  a consistent behavior locally and in the Lambda function environment, an easy way to go is to set the AWS credentials in the environment of the Lambda function.

Comment: The problem I get isn't URL length, but for whatever reason the calls from lambda give me 403s, and the locally run presigned urls without the token work fine

Comment: My bad actually, the token itself is there regardless if you attach policies or not, but when I attached the S3 policy to my IAM role created for my lambda func, the 403s stopped, even though the tokens stayed

Comment: @BrianLeishman This comment helped me solve my problem. When generating the signed url using SAM local invoke it looks like sam was using my local credentials but once I deployed my lambda I was getting 403 errors. I added the S3ReadPolicy to the lambda and this solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This also helped me to finally solve my `Access denied` issues - I changed the credentials in my `~/.aws/credentials` and now it works. What I don't understand though why supplying the credentials via `   const s3Client = new S3Client({ accessKeyId: "AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", secretAccessKey: "mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" });` didn't work. It always produced an error when trying to access the generated URL but did **not** show an error when generating the URL.

Comment: ...the keys need to be wrapped within `credentials`, e.g.  `const s3Client = new S3Client({ credentials: { accessKeyId: "AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  }  });`

Comment: Aha! Thankyou Gorgsenegger. My credentials were not wrapped like you said and my url's were getting access denied. After making that change it works. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I am using aws cli to generate the presigned url, but my IAM role is only valid for 12 hours. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), the IAM role requires at least 7 days availability. What I did was creating a new role, which has only S3 access permission, but no expiration limit. In command line, I typed

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID "your_new_aws_access_key_id"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY "your_new_aws_secret_access_key"
```

Then I run this command

```
aws s3 presign "your_target_file"
```

And it works! The very long x-amz-security-token is gone!

Comment: This answer is mostly misleading. What you actually did was switch from signing with (short-lived) STS credentials to signing with (long-lived) IAM user credentials. The fact that you used IAM user credentials is what caused the absence of x-amz-security-token in the signed URL.