# Presigned URL with IAM user from console works. From code it does not?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to generate a presigned url from my s3 bucket using an IAM user. The user permissions I have setup for the IAM user work if I log into the aws console as the IAM user and create the presigned url from there. No problem accessing the object using that url either. But when using the aws-sdk v3 I get a presigned url that returns access denied every time. I am exclusively using IAM inline permissions to control access to the buckets objects. Here is my IAM user policy ...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my Node.js code to get the presigned url from my Netlify webhook  function ...

```
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { GetObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-2', accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_FMUSER_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_FMUSER_SECRET_KEY});
    const bucket = 'myBucket';
    const file = 'testFile.zip'

    async function getSignedDownloadUrl(targetFile) {
      let command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucket, Key:targetFile });
      return await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
    }

    let url = await getSignedDownloadUrl(file);

    console.log(url)
```

The region I am setting (us-east-2) is the same region assigned to the bucket. I have read some suggestions that encryption might have something to do with it but I'm confused as to why I can get a working presigned url when logged into the console as the IAM user but the presigned url I get from code gives me access denied. Thanks

Comment: I just downloaded the AWS CLI program and generated the presigned URL from there using the same IAM user as above and it worked. So I guess my aws-sdk v3 code is wrong somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure your access tokens are being passed correctly? Request signing happens completely on the client side. The SDK will happily generate a signed URL even if your tokens are wrong, and you won't know that before you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826131/1094779) post and discovered I am passing my credentials incorrectly as Quassnoi suggested.

I needed to change S3Client call to this ...

```
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-2', credentials: {accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_FMUSER_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_FMUSER_SECRET_KEY}});
```

Thanks for the help.